# How to select hour in priority

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using C# and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have hour data like this:

```
Client_ID    TheHour    HourMin     HourMAx
53026        09:00      7           9
53026        12:00      10          12
53026        15:00      13          15
53026        18:00      16          19
```

I will put `TheHour` into my combobox, that depends on computer hour.

When the computer hour is 10:00 then the value of my combobox:

```
12:00
15:00
18:00
09:00
```

My linq is :

```
int The_Hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;

var query = from o in oEntite_T.LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE 
            where o.CLIENT_ID == CLIENT_ID && 
            The_Hour >= o.HEURE_MIN && The_Hour <= o.HEURE_MAX  
            select o;

LesListe = query.ToList();
```

It return only 1 value, which is 12:00.

That meant my combobox will select hour that depend on computer hour, but it leave the possibility for the user to select another hour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example in LINQPad, I also added a flag to indicate selected value.:

```
void Main()
{

    var LS_CLIENTHORRAIREs = new List<LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE>
    {
        new LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE{TheHour="09:00",HourMin=7,HourMAx=9},
        new LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE{TheHour="12:00",HourMin=10,HourMAx=12},
        new LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE{TheHour="15:00",HourMin=13,HourMAx=15},
        new LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE{TheHour="18:00",HourMin=16,HourMAx=19}
    };
    LS_CLIENTHORRAIREs.Dump();

    int The_Hour = 10;

    var query = from o in LS_CLIENTHORRAIREs 
            select new {o.TheHour,o.HourMin,o.HourMAx,selected = The_Hour >= o.HourMin && The_Hour <= o.HourMAx}
             ;
    query.OrderBy (q => q.HourMAx>The_Hour ? 0 : 1).ThenBy (q => q.HourMAx).Dump();
}
public class LS_CLIENTHORRAIRE
{
    public string TheHour{get;set;}
    public int HourMin{get;set;}
    public int HourMAx{get;set;}
}
```

**Results**

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you don't want to *filter* the list, you want to *sort* it, right?

First, you want to sort it by

- whether the MaxHour is in the past

and then by

- TheHour itself.

Example: Let's assume it is 10:00:

```
Client_ID    TheHour    HourMin     HourMax  MaxHourIsInThePast
53026        09:00      7           9         x
53026        12:00      10          12        
53026        15:00      13          15        
53026        18:00      16          19
```

Now you return a list that orders first by `MaxHourIsInThePast` (first those without `x` and then those with `x`) and then by `TheHour`.

Implementation is left as an exercise. Hint: You will need the LINQ `order by` keyword, and an expression similar to `(o.HourMax < currentHour ? 2 : 1)` will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume the computer hour is 10.
Then: your condition would be: `HourMin <= 10 && HoureMax >= 10`.
The first condition would return row 1 and 2. The second one would return row 2. The intersect will return only the second row, which is 12:00.

If you want to get all rows, just remove these conditions.